# Plot images from numpy.ndarray data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have a column['signal'] which composed of 500 ndarray data in each row. The length of each row is same. I would like to pick one row and plot it into picture. I tried something like data.reshape((1,-1)), but it did not work. I found many solutions on the net, but more error messages appeared.  So how can I:

1. plot an image from one row of data in that column
2. Any way to plot more images e.g. plot all images from the column in the dataset (optional question)

Here is a toy data sample:

```
   ' 19.35983', ' 19.33365', ' 19.30945', ' 19.3211',
   ' 19.34946', ' 19.37268', ' 19.38763', ' 19.4', ' 19.4063',
   ' 19.41592', ' 19.97250', ' 19.4294', ' 19.4368', ' 19.44623',
   ' 19.4646', ' 19.47464', ' 19.485', ' 19.4948', ' 19.50592',
   ' 19.51727', ' 19.51672', ' 19.5159', ' 19.52573'
```

If you can't use this data, please take any data that you believe it will help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your data seems to be in string format, so try to convert before reshaping:

```
import numpy as np

data = [' 19.35983', ' 19.33365', ' 19.30945', ' 19.3211']
lst = [float(item) for item in data]
array = np.reshape(lst, (2,2))
```

Comment: thanks @TME. The type of those date is numpy.ndarray.  I tried your solution and got two lines. Nice.  As I have 500 data in a row, how should I reshape it? I got this error message ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 500 into shape (2,500) The image should look like electric signal

Comment: Im not sure how exactly your image should look like, but in general np.reshape expects the desired size as (rows, columns):
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

So if your data contains, 500 data points you can shape it into 2 rows x 250 columns, adding up to 500: reshape(lst,(2,250))

Comment: :) I tried with array = np.reshape(lst, (-1,1)) and it showed some sort of image. Not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TME, I think I get some sort of images:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [' 19.35983', ' 19.33365', ' 19.30945', ' 19.3211']
lst = [float(item) for item in data]
array = np.reshape(lst, (-1,1))
plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))

plt.plot(array)
plt.ylabel('some numbers')

plt.show()
```

This may not be the right answer yet. If you know how to do it better or how to plot all images from that column (one row one image), please kindly advice. Thank you!